# axis pgfplots binomial law

Tags: pgfplots

i have a problem : i want the binomial law at the right place.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);},
    declare function={poisson(\k,\l)=((exp(-\l)*\l^\k))/(\k!);},    
    declare function={mu=100;}, %
    declare function={sigma=7.071;}, %
    declare function={normal(\m,\s)=1/(\s*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}
]

\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,10},
    axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=.1  ,
    xlabel = {$k$} ,
    ylabel = {$proba$ } ,
    legend style={
    at={(0,0)},
    anchor=north east,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.1)}}
]
\addplot [fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, bar width=1] {binom(x,100,0.02)};
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] {poisson(x,2)};
%\addplot [domain=40:120,samples=201,thin, smooth, color=red] {normal(mu,sigma)};
%\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,40,0.5)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i have tried with `enlargelimits=true,` it's not well :/

any ideas ?

best,

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `enlargelimits=true` with `enlarge x limits=<value>`.

It is not entirely clear, how your histogram would look. Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14192]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);},
    declare function={poisson(\k,\l)=((exp(-\l)*\l^\k))/(\k!);},
    declare function={mu=100;}, %
    declare function={sigma=7.071;}, %
    declare function={normal(\m,\s)=1/(\s*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}
]

\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,10},
    axis lines = left,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,zerofill,precision=2
                    },
    ybar=7mm, 
    bar width=4.mm,
    xlabel = {$k$},
    ylabel = {proba},
    legend pos=north east
]
\addplot [fill=red,] {binom(x,100,0.02)};
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5]   {poisson(x,2)};
\addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{scope}
```

or this:

[image]

Where axis preamble is:

```
\begin{axis}[x=11mm,
    samples at={0,...,10},
    axis lines = left,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    yticklabel style={
/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,zerofill,precision=2},
    ybar, 
    bar width=4.4 mm,
    xlabel = {$k$} ,
    ylabel = {proba} ,
    legend pos=north east
]
```

**Addendum:**
Both above solutions are based on your MWE. But, now it seems, that you looking for the following diagram:

[image]

Which is produced by:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14192]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);},
declare function={poisson(\k,\l)=((exp(-\l)*\l^\k))/(\k!);},
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,10},
    axis lines = left,
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,zerofill,precision=2
                    },
    ybar interval=0.7,
    x tick label as interval,
    xlabel = {$k$},
    ylabel = {proba},
    legend pos=north east
]
\addplot [fill=red ] {binom(x,100,0.02)};
\addplot [fill=cyan] {poisson(x,2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```